# how to expose RDDs from Spark SQL plan

Tags: apache-spark-sql, rdd, sql-execution-plan

I am seeking suggestions on how to expose RDDs from a Spark SQL physical plan (with Spark-3.2.1). Here let's take TPCH Query 1 as a concrete example.

This is the physical plan generated by `sql(query).explain()`:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) Sort [l_returnflag#17 ASC NULLS FIRST, l_linestatus#18 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
+- Exchange rangepartitioning(l_returnflag#17 ASC NULLS FIRST, l_linestatus#18 ASC NULLS FIRST, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#97]
   +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[l_returnflag#17, l_linestatus#18], functions=[sum(l_quantity#13), sum(l_extendedprice#14), sum(CheckOverflow((promote_precision(cast(l_extendedprice#14 as decimal(13,2))) * promote_precision(CheckOverflow((1.00 - promote_precision(cast(l_discount#15 as decimal(13,2)))), DecimalType(13,2), true))), DecimalType(26,4), true)), sum(CheckOverflow((promote_precision(CheckOverflow((promote_precision(cast(l_extendedprice#14 as decimal(13,2))) * promote_precision(CheckOverflow((1.00 - promote_precision(cast(l_discount#15 as decimal(13,2)))), DecimalType(13,2), true))), DecimalType(26,4), true)) * promote_precision(cast(CheckOverflow((1.00 + promote_precision(cast(l_tax#16 as decimal(13,2)))), DecimalType(13,2), true) as decimal(26,4)))), DecimalType(38,6), true)), avg(l_quantity#13), avg(l_extendedprice#14), avg(l_discount#15), count(1)], output=[l_returnflag#17, l_linestatus#18, sum_qty#114, sum_base_price#115, sum_disc_price#116, sum_charge#117, avg_qty#118, avg_price#119, avg_disc#120, count_order#121L])
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(l_returnflag#17, l_linestatus#18, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#93]
         +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[l_returnflag#17, l_linestatus#18], functions=[partial_sum(l_quantity#13), partial_sum(l_extendedprice#14), partial_sum(CheckOverflow((promote_precision(cast(l_extendedprice#14 as decimal(13,2))) * promote_precision(CheckOverflow((1.00 - promote_precision(cast(l_discount#15 as decimal(13,2)))), DecimalType(13,2), true))), DecimalType(26,4), true)), partial_sum(CheckOverflow((promote_precision(CheckOverflow((promote_precision(cast(l_extendedprice#14 as decimal(13,2))) * promote_precision(CheckOverflow((1.00 - promote_precision(cast(l_discount#15 as decimal(13,2)))), DecimalType(13,2), true))), DecimalType(26,4), true)) * promote_precision(cast(CheckOverflow((1.00 + promote_precision(cast(l_tax#16 as decimal(13,2)))), DecimalType(13,2), true) as decimal(26,4)))), DecimalType(38,6), true)), partial_avg(l_quantity#13), partial_avg(l_extendedprice#14), partial_avg(l_discount#15), partial_count(1)], output=[l_returnflag#17, l_linestatus#18, sum#155, isEmpty#156, sum#157, isEmpty#158, sum#159, isEmpty#160, sum#161, isEmpty#162, sum#163, count#164L, sum#165, count#166L, sum#167, count#168L, count#169L])
            +- *(1) Project [l_quantity#13, l_extendedprice#14, l_discount#15, l_tax#16, l_returnflag#17, l_linestatus#18]
               +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
                  +- FileScan parquet tpch_100.lineitem[l_quantity#13,l_extendedprice#14,l_discount#15,l_tax#16,l_returnflag#17,l_linestatus#18,l_shipdate#24] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(2436 paths)[hdfs://node13-opa:8020/user/spark_benchmark/tpch_100/dataset/lineit..., PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(l_shipdate#24), (l_shipdate#24 <= 1998-09-02)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<l_quantity:decimal(12,2),l_extendedprice:decimal(12,2),l_discount:decimal(12,2),l_tax:deci...
```

These are the generated RDDs by `sql(query).rdd.toDebugString`:

```
(4) MapPartitionsRDD[17] at rdd at <console>:24 []
 |  SQLExecutionRDD[16] at rdd at <console>:24 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[15] at rdd at <console>:24 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[14] at rdd at <console>:24 []
 |  ShuffledRowRDD[13] at rdd at <console>:24 []
 +-(200) MapPartitionsRDD[12] at rdd at <console>:24 []
     |   MapPartitionsRDD[8] at rdd at <console>:24 []
     |   ShuffledRowRDD[7] at rdd at <console>:24 []
     +-(265) MapPartitionsRDD[6] at rdd at <console>:24 []
         |   MapPartitionsRDD[5] at rdd at <console>:24 []
         |   MapPartitionsRDD[4] at rdd at <console>:24 []
         |   FileScanRDD[3] at rdd at <console>:24 []
```

I know the process of RDDs generation is to 1) create the input RDD (e.g. `FileScanRDD[3]`) from the input data; 2) do transformations based on the input RDD for each physical operator.

**My question is: whether/how the internal "transformations" code is able to be exposed outside the Spark SQL?**

For example, a user can create the initial RDD, like `FileScanRDD[3]`, from the input data, whether/how *the user* (rather than the internal Spark SQL) is able to implement the same "transformation" on `FileScanRDD[3]` to produce `MapPartitionsRDD[4]`, and later for the rest of RDDs?

Appreciate your help in advance!